# Integrating Google Login in Unity3d iOS

Tags: ios7, unity-game-engine, google-signin

I want to integrate google login in unity so that it can be ported to almost all Operating Systems. I tried stack and unity3d forum but could not find a suitable post. Downloaded a lot of code examples but of no use.

-> I read that there's a paid plugin 'Prime31' but i don't want to pay money for it.

-> I found some code from google in .NET that can be used to authenticate users but i was unable to add that zip file into unity. It could only be opened by MonoDevelop but then also could be added.  https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list

Also Found another plugin from gitHub but was again unable to use that.[Unity GPGPlugin](https://github.com/faizann/UnityGPGPlugin)

I just want to give options to the users that **they can either login** with facebook or google account and then play the game.

I am quite new to unity so any **code/hint/logic** would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

As far as I can tell, this is an official Google made plugin. I use it, and it's pretty easy. Its documentation is plenty thorough. It has been updated to the new all in one GMS jar. It works for both iOS and android. If you use it with their supplied [admob](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins) plugin (which in Unity works a lot like the android sdk), you'll have to delete one file (both plugins define the same class, it doesn't seem to matter which version you keep).

edit: Unity will tell you which class has been duplicated.

Comment: Google Play Services' IOS support is deprecated.